# Xquery for following-siblings, but contiguous?

Tags: xpath, xquery

I need an XPath query that originates at node 'a' to return some number of contiguously-following 'b' nodes and some number of contiguously-following 'c' nodes. So in this snippet-

```
<a />
<b />
<b />
<c />
<d />
<e />
<a />
<b />
<b />
<b />
<b />
<c />
```

it would be-

```
<b />
<b />
<c />
```

If I ran it against the first 'a' node and

```
<b />
<b />
<b />
<b />
<c />
```

If I ran it against the 2nd.

Ordering matters and I can't find a solution that does not involve unioning separate expressions.

Comment: Please be clear about whether you're limited to XPath or can use XQuery, show what you tried and provide well-formed input. A bunch of root-level elements will never form a well-formed XML document.

Answer (score 0):

The best bet for this is probably a recursive function something like

```
declare function local:successors($n as node()) as node()* {
  if ($n/following-sibling::*[1][self::b|self::c])
  then ($n, local-successors($n/following-sibling::*[1])
  else $n
};

local:successors($a)
```

That's assuming you want XQuery as in your title, not XPath as in the body of your question.